# Blender Mirroring Rotations

Tags: animation, rigging, mirror

[image]

I use the method of Ctrl + C and then Ctrl + Shift + V to copy and paste my rotations of the arm to the other side, but it doesn't seem to work. The origin point of the character is at 0, 0, 0. The arm seems to be veering to the left (character's perspective) and is not where it should be (towards the center like the right arm). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you make sure to do Shift + C before to do your rotation, that may be the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I solved my own issue! I just went to edit mode and reset the roll of the arm and hand to 0. This made it all weird, but when I fixed the pose it mirrored perfectly!